# Why hasn't Russia or China come up with any system yet to bypass USD?

Tags: united-states, economy, russian-federation, china, sanctions

- [China urged to tap RCEP trade deal for future digital payments system as US sanctions loom](https://www.scmp.com/economy/china-economy/article/3117925/china-urged-tap-rcep-trade-deal-future-digital-payments)

> China should consider using digital technology to develop an alternative to the SWIFT financial payments system as a way of insulating itself from being cut off from the US-dominated financial messaging service, according to Liu Xiaochun, deputy dean of the Shanghai New Finance Research Institute.

So, my question is: why hasn't either Russia or China done that already?

**already** is the keyword here as Russia is dealing with US sanctions for years now. And, China is dealing with US hostility from the start of Trump's presidency which signals that China is no longer safe from possible large scale US sanctions.

Comment: Swift and the USD aren't exactly synonymous. Your title q asks one thing and your body q another. Swift (as a company) is actually [based in the EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_for_Worldwide_Interbank_Financial_Telecommunication). It's true that US sanctions (transitively) threatening EU companies often get them to comply to US wishes... but what exactly is your q here? Why don't Russia and China separate their banking from the US *and* the EU?

Comment: As the article linked says, both China and Russia have parallel systems for their own banks (CIPS and SPFS) already.

Comment: It may be based even on Sent Kits and Nevis, it is still a US instrument: https://blockonomi.com/swift-military/

Comment: @user2501323: to clarify: why aren't Russia and Venezuela exchanging USD over something other than Swift is one question. Why is Saudi Arabia not accepting payments in rubles (crypto or not) is a somewhat different question.

Comment: Yes. Questions seems to be a bit broad, but still interesting to not close.

Comment: (@Fizz) and SWIFT supports transactions in all currencies used by its customer banks, not just USD -- but that's irrelevant to sanctions by US (or anyone else)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't bypass the dollar without having a comparably sized economy that is not dependent on the dollar. There are two big main factors that make replacing the dollar difficult. The practical one is you need a market that has the same volume as the dollar, moving billions of dollars is trivial (for moving billions). Secondly you need a market independent of the dollar, because the U.S. will fight a challenge to the dollar as it being the standard of international trade is massively beneficial.

China may have the economic size to compete, but they are far too dependent on U.S. trade to actually take on such a fight. They also have trust issues since they have shown in the past a willingness to manipulate currency to their advantage which encourages other countries to avoid holding any such currency for prolonged periods. Russia lacks the economy to truly challenge the U.S.

Comment: "willingness to manipulate currency" - is it a way worser, than controlling dollar transactions?????

Comment: @user2501323 Yes. manipulating value is huge in an international currency. Not being able to do X with dollars can suck, but it's way better than Y dollars losing 20% of their purchasing power overnight.

Comment: "You can't bypass the dollar without having a comparably sized economy" - emm, last China move about economical zone in pacific overweights US and making a place for China doing business. Closed place and without the US. "losing 20%" is still better than money being "freezed on accounts because we want it", like with Iran/Venezuela, isn't it?

Comment: @user2501323 If you truly believe that whatever nation's money were to take over from the dollar, that that nation would never do the same thing eventually, you are naive. I understand that much of the rest of the world views America as evil for some of its practices, but I firmly believe that any national superpower would not be any better, and may very well end up being worse.

Comment: A significant factor in China's inability to set up an alternative system are capital controls. You can't take or transfer more than 20k RMB ($3k) out of China without a special permission.

Comment: @dbkk So you think the leaders of China sits and think "We could compete with the dollar if only someone would let use change the law to move money out. Wonder who could change that law!"

Comment: Why can't they have their own system for moving dollars?

Comment: @pipe: it's not that they are that stupid, but there are significant political risks for an authoritarian regime not to have those kinds of controls.

Comment: @user253751: They can to the extent that the US doesn't decide to block their  correspondent accounts (see my answer for details on that). Presently the US uses that measure (very) sparingly. Otherwise it's basically down to moving cash as the system if the currency issuer country decides on that kind of "total banking blockade" for the banks of another country. (As bad as the US and China or Russia relations may have gotten, it didn't get to anything resembling that, although the US-Iran relations are basically on that level now.)

Comment: @pipe: [basically](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03085147.2020.1718913) it's part of the mechanisms that force foreign companies to create local joint ventures.

Comment: @pipe Chinese gov't needs to balance competing priorities. Keeping capital controls seems more important than making an attempt to compete with USD in international money transfers, with an uncertain chance of success.

Comment: Also, oil trades in US dollars so if you need to buy or sell oil you need US dollars.

Answer (score 10):

Some reasons why a [CDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_bank_digital_currency) (be it called "digital rouble" or more improperly "crypto-ruble") [might not](https://www.globaltradelawblog.com/2018/01/10/crypto-rouble/) actually be that effective at bypassing US sanctions-- basically because simply using it will raise red flags and possibly attract US investigations and sanctions:

> the ability of a crypto-rouble to help Russia evade U.S. sanctions is limited. Prohibited transactions would be continue to prohibited regardless of the means of exchange. Theoretically, it would be harder to get caught if you’re using currency that cannot be detected by U.S. regulators. But it is unclear just how many world financial actors would accept Russian government crypto-rouble surveillance, in exchange for protection from scrutiny by U.S. financial regulators. For this reason, the primary user of the crypto-ruble might be the Russian state itself.
>
> [...]
>
> if a crypto-rouble were to be issued by the Russian central bank (or even by a commercial bank in Russia), then the very existence of that platform would lend itself to detection. Although the currency itself could be secure, exchanges denominated in the currency would likely flow in more predictable paths than standard crypto-currencies. Thus it would only be a matter of time before U.S. enforcement agencies could identify red flags and investigate potentially prohibited transactions.
>
> An executive at Gazprombank, the state-run bank that is subject to U.S. sectoral sanctions, acknowledged that “[c]rypto isn’t the answer in a quick way.”

As was actually noted in the OP's article, both China and Russia have parallel systems [relative to Swift] for their own banks ([CIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Border_Inter-Bank_Payments_System) and [SPFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPFS)) already. The real issue/question is: why would some other country [not] use them. The Wikipedia article on the latter cites Russian state sources that interoperability deals have been reached with China, India, Iran, and some other coutries and that 15% of Russia's internal transactions use the system. But it's a little unclear how widely adopted it is outside. (The Wikipedia article on China's system lacks concrete data.) But for many other countries, the question is basically: why bother?

A somewhat subtle aspect here is (as explained in the CIPS article) is that the system itself only sends orders, but that actual settlement happens through correspondent accounts. And these are also on the [target list of US sanctions](https://www.anticorruptionblog.com/anti-corruption/new-ofac-capta-list-targets-foreign-banks).

As Wikipedia [explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondent_account) the concept:

> A bank will typically require correspondent accounts for holding currencies outside of jurisdictions where it has a branch or affiliate. This is because most central bank settlement systems do not register deposits or transfer funds to banks not doing business in their countries. With few exceptions, the actual funds held in any foreign currency account (whether for a bank or for its customer) are held in the bank's correspondent account in that currency's home country.

So you couldn't exchange (bank) dollars in the usual manner if the US government puts your banks on their CAPTA list. (I'll also note that this list is rather new, and hasn't been used extensively insofar. Presumably it was added in view of possible bypass of Swift as by using different order messaging platforms like CIPS/SPFS.)

So you'd either have to pay with dollars in suitcases as Iran [started to do](https://www.pri.org/stories/2014-01-21/when-banks-dont-work-suitcase-full-cash-will-suffice) and I think still does now [to some extent (even with Russia)](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2020/12/25/1m-of-iranian-cash-stashed-in-vodka-box-stolen-from-russian-foreign-ministry-a72481) , or you'd have to use a different currency altogether... which gets to the bigger issue of whom accepts what currency as payment, which Ryathal's answer addresses already.

Comment: I think now "attract sanctions" seems a bit irrelevant - sanctions would be anyway. So...

Comment: @user2501323: it's the 3rd party who would attract them. E.g. if some company in Mexico starts using digital roubles, the US might decide to sanction that company just for that, meaning the company would have to choose between doing business with Russia or with the US, but not both. Additionally, if the Mexican government chooses to obey US demands, they could fine the Mexican company etc.

Comment: Now I get it. But. US might decide to sanction any company in the world - for example for doing business with Russia (NS-2 is a good example). By any reason it may decide worth it. You may surrender, or try to dedollarize. At the moment when international payments would flow in crypto-smth, exchanged by gold - in that moment sanctions would be irrelevant

Comment: @user2501323 Yeah, but getting to the point where EVERYONE (or at least large enough part) is using it the hard part. How many companies can seriously de-dollarize fast enough to not be hit by it and do it in a manner that would allow them to also have compatriots supporting them (who would be willing to take that risk) in it without folding? And what's their incentive? What pros does it have that are large enough that the risk is deemed woth it by conservative majority?

Comment: That depends on de-dollarizing countries. Ten years ago that sounds as political sci-fi. Now, it becomes reality. Slowly, but still becomes. There are just two choices: living under threat of sanctions, or dedollarize. Of course, it is relevant for non-western countries - western don't need it that much.

Comment: Just like Bitcoin used to... but no longer does? (because Bitcoin got integrated into the dollar-based economy I suppose via speculators)

Comment: (in which case the solution is obviously for Russia to design a currency that wildly fluctuates in value so that USAnians will pour all their dollars into it!)

Comment: @user253751: LOL.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's, obviously, a complex thing to do!

But process of ["dedollarization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedollarisation) is in progress. In fact, developing projects of [digital-yuan](https://www.investopedia.com/understanding-chinas-digital-yuan-5090699) and [digital-rouble](http://cbr.ru/eng/press/event/?id=8176) crypto-currencies are part of that work.

EU is also partially [edging](https://asia.nikkei.com/Economy/China-Russia-and-EU-edge-away-from-petrodollar) from petrodollar.

US sanctions are boosting those processes, because more and more countries realizing its vulnerability. But dedollarization is still complex and hard to achieve.

Maintaining economical ties is also important for it, and here China is far above all others:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not my DV since this answer is somewhat correct, but the crypto-yuan and the crypto-ruble have little in common despite their similar names. The latter was indeed created to make Russia-Venezuela transaction easier, but Russia's central bank has [no plans](https://www.reuters.com/article/russia-cenbank-rouble/russian-banks-fear-digital-rouble-could-hit-profits-says-central-bank-idUSL8N2IJ4GE) for a cryptocurrency that can be used domestically. The crypto-yuan is exactly the opposite in these regards (if you read the article you've linked to).

Comment: With all respect, I've read it twice, and do not found anything about "no plans". Private banks are unhappy - that was expected. But nothing about "no plans". "The digital rouble may create new risks. We are closely studying them." and then "The central bank first floated the idea of the digital rouble in October, saying it may issue it on top of existing cash and non-cash roubles to facilitate payments for individuals and businesses". Really, @Fizz, it's first time I see you've mistaked.

Comment: I guess you don't understand the difference between a digital currency and a cryptocurrency.

Comment: Russian CB is talking about digital currency - some crypto, issued by Central Bank. Crypto-Yuan is, in fact the same - something issued by a China CB, but China is "carrying lantern under the basket", as usual. Chinese currency is just called "crypto", but inside it is the same - digital version of yuan

Comment: Just another point to Crypto-Yuan being, in fact, digital currency: https://www.dw.com/en/china-digital-currency-yuan-bitcoin/a-55134692 . Also. How do you create that pretty small-links in comments??

Comment: Yeah you're right, the crypto-yuan is basically the same kind of instrument as the "digital ruble"; both are [CBDCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_bank_digital_currency). I don't know how the crypto-ruble used between Russian and Venezuela relates to the digital ruble (that's going to be used domestically. They could be completely different instruments.) By the way, CBR itself explains "Why a digital ruble is not a cryptocurrency" https://www.cbr.ru/eng/analytics/d_ok/dig_ruble/

Comment: Ok I'm upvoting now; FYI: I'm still a bit dubious about the claim that a digital Yuan will help displace the dollar much, so I've asked on econ SE https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/42220/why-it-said-that-a-digital-yuan-or-some-other-similar-currency-turned-into-a-cd

Comment: @user2501323 please explain "carrying lantern under the basket". It is not an English idiom.

Comment: @user253751 I guess it is the same as "hiding its light under a bushel" (which is an English idiom at least 400 years old).